# standard notation and the numbered notation

Tags: piano, notation, beginner, sight-reading, numbered-notation

So I have been playing piano for 1.5 years and my biggest obstacle for learning piano is definitely to play both hand, I’m still struggling right now, maybe I improve a little bit, but still very much struggling.

I don’t have much problem with the standard notation (the dotted one) my biggest problem one more time is playing with both hands. However I find it easier to play using the numbered notation. When I want to learn Turkish march I try draw everything on the blank page using the numbered notation, and I find it easier though I still struggle when playing with both hand but overall easier probably 30% than using the standard notation. But what I don’t understand is why there are not many people using the numbered notation? When so many people struggling using the standard notation? I was searching for piece that using the numbered notation and I barely find any song that using the numbered notation? Can someone tell me why numbered notation is not used? My second question is if I switch to use the numbered notation, will it be alright? Or maybe numbered notation is barely use by people because it will get complicated later on, I mean like the drawing will be complicated? Idk whether I should stick using the standard notation (dotted one) or the numbered notation.

Comment: Are you playing from numbered-notation music printed in China?

Comment: @Aaron i think yes its from china, like C = 1 , D = 2, E = 3 , F=4, G= 5, A = 6 and B = 7. Its the same numbered notation when i learned melodica only using one hand in elementary school.

Comment: You want to try converting https://imslp.org/wiki/6_Little_Piano_Pieces,_Op.19_(Schoenberg,_Arnold) to the numbered notation?  (Note: this is still under copyright in the EU, so you can't download it there.)

Answer (score 1):

The **numbered notation system**, or jiǎnpǔ, is a common music notation system in China; however, it is nearly unheard of (for piano music, at least) elsewhere. Standard piano music is always (or near always) written in western notation ("dots").

There is at least one music notation program that can convert between western notation and Jianpu.

> **NoteAbilityPro** allows you to enter music using this system or to convert between JianPu and western notation.

> The **Convert to JianPu** and **Convert to Western** are used to convert selected areas of your score from one notation system to the other. Ornaments and symbols will not be converted, but all the notes will be converted using the current key as a guide. ([SOURCE](http://debussy.music.ubc.ca/Helpfiles/IPad/pages/CypherNotation.html))

However, keep in mind that Jianpu is a simplified notation and cannot represent many of the symbols and musical constructs present in piano music.

That said, if you can find versions of the music you want that are created with Noteability Pro, then you should be able to convert them to numbered notation.

---

For advice on playing with both hands, there are many posts on this site. As a starting place, try:

- [How can I significantly improve my hand independence on piano?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/how-can-i-significantly-improve-my-hand-independence-on-piano?rq=1).
- [Search for the [hand-independence] tag](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hand-independence)

---

Regarding the Turkish March specifically, this is a relatively advanced piece. It is not surprising that it would be a challenge to play hands together.